# Prove that $I^2/\partial I^2 \simeq I/\partial I \wedge I/\partial I$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, compactness, spheres

Define $X \wedge Y := X \times Y/\left(\lbrace x_0\rbrace \times Y \cup X \times \lbrace y_0\rbrace\right)$. I'd like to prove that $I^n/\partial I^n \simeq \mathbb{S}^n$, the unit sphere.

To do so I'd like to using induction with the help of :

> Lemma : if $X,Y$, are Hausdorff compact spaces then the [Alexandroff compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of $\overset{\wedge}{\left(X \setminus \lbrace x_0\rbrace  \times Y \setminus \lbrace y_0\rbrace \right)}$ (where the wedge simbol indicates the compactification) is homeomorphic to $X \wedge Y$.

This is a neat proof of $I^n/\partial I^n \simeq \mathbb{S}^n$ but I don't get the $n=2$ step, which apparently involves using :

$$I^2/\partial I^2 \simeq I/\partial I \wedge I/\partial I$$

I thought I could do a map from $I/\partial I \times I/\partial I \longrightarrow I^2/\partial I^2$ which is costant on $I/\partial I \times \lbrace x_0\rbrace \cup \lbrace y_0\rbrace \times I/\partial I$ but seems rather complicated.

Any help with the proof or alternative solution to $I^2/\partial I^2 \simeq I/\partial I \wedge I/\partial I$ would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply the lemma also for the $n = 2$ step. Just take $X = Y = I/\partial I$ and $x_0 = y_0 = *$ = equivalence class of $\partial I$. Then $X \setminus \{x_0\} = Y \setminus \{y_0\} = (0,1)$, hence $(X \setminus \{x_0\}) \times (Y \setminus \{y_0\}) = (0,1)^2$. This is an open square and its one-point compactification is clearly $I^2/\partial I^2$.

Comment: The "clearly" I have in mind is to define $f: I^2 \longrightarrow \overset{\wedge}{(0,1)^{2}}$ defined by $f(x,y) = (x,y)$ if $(x,y) \not\in \partial I^2$, or $\lbrace \infty \rbrace$ otherwise, where $\infty$ is the point added to form compactification. This map is a closed identification so the induced map would be the desidered homeomorphism. Do you have a simple way to show that $f$ is continuos?

Comment: @jacopoburelli It is clearly continuous in all $(x,y) \in (0,1)^2$. For $(x,y) \in \partial I^2$ we have $f(x,y) = \infty$. Given an open neighborhood $U$ of $\infty$, we know that $U = (0,1)^\setminus K$ for some compact $K \subset (0,1)^2$. But then $V = I^2 \setminus K$ is an open neighborhood of $(x,y)$ such that $f(V) = U$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $I / \partial I$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ via $\theta \mapsto \exp(2\pi i \theta)$. Consider the fundamental polygon of the torus $I / \partial I \times I / \partial I$:

[image: Fundamental polygon of the torus]

By definition, $I / \partial I \wedge I / \partial I$ is the result of collapsing the boundary of this fundamental polygon to a single point. In other words,
$$
I / \partial I \wedge I / \partial I \cong I^2 / \partial I^2.
$$

Comment: That's exactly the part I don't understand, why could you easily afirm the homeomorphism?

Comment: You mean the last homeomorphism? In both cases, we take the unit square $I^2$ and identify the boundary to a point. Thus, the result is one and the same.